# any way I can use gcov to report which source code lines are covered by specific tests?

Tags: gcc, gcov

Currently, the way I have gcov set up is that I run a set of test files on compiled C++ source code. I can then see which lines aren’t covered by *any* of the test files. I’d ideally like to be able to easily see which tests cover specific lines. The difficulty is that currently tests are parallelized and I want to keep that behavior, so the idea of running one test at a time and saving the .gcda file with execution counters probably can’t work. The other difficulty I’m running into is that you can’t instruct gcov to name gcda files anything other than your program binary’s name. So running a bunch of tests concurrently and mv’ing the gcda file seems tricky because of a race condition where two runs of gcov write to the same gcda file. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: If the tests are parallelized, don't you already have a race condition where two runs of gcov write to the same gcda file?

Comment: @ssbssa the gcda file is generated/updated when you run your binary

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean. If you run your binary parallel, then multiple instances may update the gcda file at the same time.